# OpenLayers 3.7 projection

Tags: openlayers

I've been trying to get some GeoJSON features into OpenLayers. 3.7 changed the geojson source format, and I've made the changes. But I don't know how to reproject in the new format from 4326 to 3857.

Here is the link to fiddle.net (https://jsfiddle.net/aborrell/h2yv6moy/) :

As it shows, the features are near 0,0, but actually they should be in Mexico.

Comment: Please, look at the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2yv6moy/1/).